# `import readline from 'readline'` gets compilation error in Codeforces

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, es6-modules

During solving problems in codeforces with javascript(Node.js Lang), given that all other statements are same, whenever I use

```
import readline from 'readline';
```

I get Compilation error. But whenever I use

```
const readline = require('readline')
```

My code is accepted. Why?

The code below gets `compilation error`.

```
import readline from 'readline';
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', (input) => {
    const [s, v1, v2, t1, t2] = input.split(' ').map(Number);

    const time_required_for_first_participant = s * v1  +  2 * t1;
    const time_required_for_second_participant = s * v2  +  2 * t2;

    if (time_required_for_first_participant < time_required_for_second_participant) {
        console.log('First');
    } else if (time_required_for_first_participant > time_required_for_second_participant) {
        console.log('Second');
    } else {
        console.log('Friendship');
    }

    rl.close();
});
```

But the code below is `accepted`.

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', (input) => {
    const [s, v1, v2, t1, t2] = input.split(' ').map(Number);

    const timeFirstParticipant = s * v1 + 2 * t1;
    const timeSecondParticipant = s * v2 + 2 * t2;

    if (timeFirstParticipant < timeSecondParticipant) {
        console.log('First');
    } else if (timeFirstParticipant > timeSecondParticipant) {
        console.log('Second');
    } else {
        console.log('Friendship');
    }

    rl.close();
});
```

Comment: what do you mean `compilation error`? javscript is an interpreted language and is not compiled ... the difference though is `import` vs `require` ... depends on what you've set as `type` in `package.json` ... `import` only works if you have type `module`

Comment: what is codeforces?